# Hue install on vanilla hadoop

Tags: user-interface, installation, hadoop

Has anyone tried to install HUE on Apache Hadoop? We are using hadoop 0.20.2 and I want to know if anyone has had success with it before I invest time doing it. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its not possible...
http://getsatisfaction.com/cloudera/topics/issue_with_cloudera_plugin_loading_in_hadoop

Comment: Thanks oae. We finally moved to CDH, so this is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Hue](http://gethue.com) also works with vanilla Hadoop, BigTop and some Cloudera competitors distributions.

The main problem before was the use of a Job Tracker plugin which was not supported until 0.23+ or 1.2+: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-461

Obviously, the integration/testing/support is much better with CDH.