# open source GUI tool for hadoop?

Tags: apache, hadoop, hue

Is there any good open source GUI tool for hadoop?

"Hue" looks like a good one but it appears that we need to install hadoop from CDH (so in some sense we are tied with Cloudera's hadoop implementations?) From this perspective, "Hue" doesn't look like a "real" open-source GUI tool... Is this correct?

Has anyone been successfully used Hue on Apache Hadoop?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect, Hue is open source (http://gethue.com) and works with vanilla Hadoop, BigTop and some Cloudera competitors distributions. Hue is a view on top of Hadoop APIs.

Obviously, the integration/testing/support is much better with CDH.

Comment: I actually found in this link that someone said Hue will only work with CDH's package of hadoop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936523/hue-install-on-vanilla-hadoop

Comment: The main problem before was the use of a Job Tracker plugin which was not supported until 0.23+ or 1.2+: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-461

Comment: So in other words, if I download apache hadoop and Hue, I should be able to run Hue on top of apache hadoop?  thanks!